# Android Static Model always returning null

Tags: android

I currently am using AsynchttpClient to make a POST request to a web server. When I debug, I can clearly see the JSON that is being returned. However, when I set the variable to a static method in the ECUser class, I always get that the ECUser.getCurrentUser() is null which shouldn't be correct. Since all the methods in ECUser is static, I don't see what my problem is.

The same thing happens if I try to assign a jsonobject to the responseBody from the asynchttpclient call. After the anonymous class terminates, the jsonobject is always null for some reason.

```
private void attemptLogin(){
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("email", userEmail.getText().toString());
        params.put("password", userPass.getText().toString());
        ECApiManager.post(Constants.loginAPI, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject responseBody) {
                //called when response code 200
                try{
                    ECUser.setCurrentUser(new ECUser(responseBody));
                    Log.d("login", responseBody.toString());
                }catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });

        if (ECUser.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            ((OnLoginListener) getActivity()).loginSuccessful(false);
        }
```

This is my ECUser Class.

```
public class ECUser {


    private static ECUser currentUser;
    private static String userToken;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private static String userID;
    private JSONObject jObject;
    private boolean loginSuccess;


    public ECUser(JSONObject data) throws JSONException {
        this.jObject = data;
        try {
            this.loginSuccess = Boolean.parseBoolean(this.jObject.getString("success"));
            if (this.loginSuccess) {
                this.userToken = this.jObject.getString("token");
                this.firstName = this.jObject.getJSONObject("user").getString("firstname");
                this.lastName = this.jObject.getJSONObject("user").getString("lastname");
                this.userID = this.jObject.getJSONObject("user").getString("id");
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method that refreshes the state of the current user by calling the API again.
     */
    public static void refreshCurrentUser() {
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("token", userToken);
        //Gotta put in user ID too.
        params.put("user_id", userID);
        // TODO: This should only call https://edu.chat/api/user, @JACOB
        ECApiManager.get(Constants.refreshUserAPI, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject responseBody) {

                try {
                    ECUser.setCurrentUser(new ECUser(responseBody));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
    }

    // Static

    public static ECUser getCurrentUser() {
        return ECUser.currentUser;
    }

    public static void setCurrentUser(ECUser user) {ECUser.currentUser = user;}

    public static String getUserToken() {
        return ECUser.userToken;
    }

    // Dynamic

    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public boolean getLoginSuccessful() {
        return this.loginSuccess;
    }


}
```

Comment: Why use HttpClient rather than HttpUrlCOnnection? Also, using static methods is considered bad programming practice.

Comment: Is it an async call?

Comment: @Christine I'd say using static methods *inappropriately* is a bad programming practice.

Comment: No, its not an async call. I put it in asynctask before and I get did not call looper.prepare()

Comment: Dave, very very rarely a static method is appropriate. Imho....

Answer (score 1):

You treat the login attempt in `ECApiManager#post` as a synchronous method, e.g. one that returns once the attempt is completed. And so, right after calling `post` you check the current user.

But, clearly from the name of the http client (`AsynchttpClient`) you can understand that the post is an asynchronous call, which means that the HTTP request will be performed in the background, and once completed successfully, it will call your `JsonHttpResponseHandler#onSuccess` method. This means that although the `ECApiManager#post` will return immediately, the current user is not set yet.

When programming in asynchronous mode, you need to handle events as they occur, and not just call everything in sequence. If you do want to make this synchronous, you will need either to use a synchronous http client (such as HttpClient or HttpUrlConnection), or add a [`Semaphore`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) to wait for your HTTP request to be completed.

For example:

```
private void attemptLogin(){
    Semaphore sema = Semaphore(1);
    sema.acquire();
    // ....
    ECApiManager.post(Constants.loginAPI, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject responseBody) {
            //called when response code 200
            try{
                ECUser.setCurrentUser(new ECUser(responseBody));
                Log.d("login", responseBody.toString());
            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                sema.release();
            }
        }

    });
    sema.acquire();
    if (ECUser.getCurrentUser() == null) {
        ((OnLoginListener) getActivity()).loginSuccessful(false);
    }
```

Note, that if you use a semaphore you will need to release it upon failure as well.

Comment: Could you give an example of how I would use lock in this situation? Is it like calling countdownlatchsignal?